# Invoke-Sqlcmd on multiple computers powershell for serverproperty edition

Tags: powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I am trying to run the below command:

```
"SQL Version" = (Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')"})
```

The Output just shows:

```
SQL Version                  : System.Data.DataRow
```

How do I get it to show the actual results?

Answer (score 0):

Your getting back the whole row of data, you need to select it with the `.Item` property, if you still do it all in one line it would look like below(assuming that 'edition' is the heading for the column you are accessing.

`"SQL Version" = (Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')"}).Item['edition']`

Although on an unrelated note please don't use spaces in variable names, makes everything so much less clear and wrapping variable names in quotes is a weird syntax.

Comment: I hate spaces as well, but the output is crucial for parsing not done by myself.  I am getting this now:  Cannot index into a null array.

Comment: I got another function to work "SQL Version" = (Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-SQLSvrVer $Computer}) but it outputs:  SQL Version       : @{Edition=Express Edition}

Comment: I got it:  "SQL Version" = (Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-SQLSvrVer $Computer} | foreach { $_.Edition })